# PDF/A-1b compliance problem with dc:title

Tags: java, maven, itext, jasper-reports, pdfa

#### Problem:

I'm trying to create a PDF/A-1b compliant file, starting from java using JasperReports.
I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC for checking the file with *preflight* tool, which is giving me an error regarding the field `dc:title` , this is the error's screenshot:

[image: Preflight error]

I've tried setting the property in any possible way, but I still getting this error and I can't figure why. I've tried reading at http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/dc:title , but I didn't find nothing useful.
I have a suspicion about this report regarding metadata - > advanced -> http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1 , where I see there is a `dc:title` empty, and a `dc:title[1]` filled, but I don't know how to set the first one.

#### Code snippet

```
    Session session = getMyConnection();
    SessionImpl sessionImpl = (SessionImpl) session;
    Connection conn = sessionImpl.connection();
    String title = "Test title";

    Map<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put(JRHibernateQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_HIBERNATE_SESSION, session);
    hm.put("ID", getTestId();
    hm.put("reportTitle", title); //Title here
    hm.put("info.title", title); //Title here

    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
            .compileReport("c:/eglobal/TEST_REPORT.jrxml");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, hm, conn);
    jasperPrint.setProperty(PdfExporterConfiguration.PROPERTY_METADATA_TITLE, title); //Title here

    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
    configuration.setPdfaConformance(PdfaConformanceEnum.PDFA_1B);
    configuration.setIccProfilePath("c:/eglobal/AdobeRGB1998.icc");
    configuration.setMetadataTitle(title); //Title here
    configuration.setDisplayMetadataTitle(true);

    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("c:/eglobal/TEST_REPORT.PDF"));
    exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
    exporter.exportReport();
```

As you can see the title is setted in every possible way ( see `//Title here` comment): I've tried with each of them individually, and nothing changes.

#### Library

These are the libraries I'm using

```
    <jasperVersion>6.16.0</jasperVersion>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>${jasperVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>${jasperVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-metadata</artifactId>
        <version>${jasperVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reading code into `JRPdfExporter` inside JasperReport lib, I've found a comment saying:

> iText 2.1.7 does not properly write localized properties and
> keywords. XMP metadata might be non conforming, include the Adobe XMP
> library to correct

So I've discovered inside of Jasper Report's `pom.xml` that there is a specific Adobe library (set as optional inside that pom):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.xmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmpcore</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Adding this dependency in my pom solved the problem